# Save state of checkbox in single choice list while navigating to another activity

Tags: android

How can i Save state of checkbox in single choice list  while navigating to another activity & come back to previous activity. Any code snippet would be appreciated. Thanx in advance

Comment: Try my answer below and if it works please mark the question as answered.

Comment: I would `Extend PreferenceActivity` . Even if its a just a simple preference, extending the Android class PreferenceActivity is nice since it takes care of saving and persisiting preferences for you, you can have a separate activity manage your preferences completely and it could be launched from the android menu.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just save the value in SharedPreferences.

Reference is here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Example here:  http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

You will want to save the current value each time it changes in a shared preference value.

and have initMethod called in onCreate() and perhaps onStart() as well that checks the to see if the value is set in the SharedPreferences and if so initialize to that value.

There are numerous tutorials on SharedPreferences, they are definitely the place to store this kind of data. Otherwise you would need to subclass the Application object which is not a good idea.

Comment: isn't this is an half the answer, like comment. there are others things missing like loading values from SharedPreferences when you return back to your activity.

Comment: Yes, now i call it an answer, :) +1

Comment: @ CodeDroid what if i want only one checkbox to be selected now i am getting all the checkbox selected

Comment: You also might want to use Radio Buttons instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you may want to do.

### #1 Pass data into another activity

intent.putExtra("keyName", "somevalue");

We can add multiple entries here. This is a key,value pair. So to receive this data from the receiving activity we have to write this code

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null)
{
String value = extras.getString("keyName");
}

Read more: http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-pass-data-to-activity.html#ixzz24FoEOTwH

### #2 Using Shared Preferences

Tons of info on this.

Easiest way to store data in Android.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

http://www.slideshare.net/androidstream/sharedpreferences-tutorial

### #3 Using SQLite DB

Databases are great, might be going to far for just saving a checkmark

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: You left out startActivityForResult()

Comment: Just grabbed it from the link. Just trying to expose to OP that this kind of method is available. Thanks though, that will help people not familiar to it.